# how to edit recurrance events using microsoft graph api with the option to edit only this and following events,this event as shown in screenshot?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

[refer image for the type of edit option using microsoft graph api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Pwp.png)

```
  var stfulltext = 'Eastern Standard Time'
  var options = { method: 'PATCH',
    url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/'+newArray[0].id+'/calendar/events/'+eventslist1[0].microsoft_id,
    headers: 
    { 'content-type': 'application/json',
      authorization: 'Bearer '+accesstoken,
      prefer: `outlook.timezone="${stfulltext}"` },
      body: 
      {
        "originalStartTimeZone": stfulltext,
        "originalEndTimeZone": stfulltext,
        "responseStatus": {
          "response": "organizer",
          "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "start": {
              "dateTime": outlook_start_time,
              "timeZone": stfulltext
          },
          "end": {
              "dateTime": outlook_end_time,
              "timeZone": stfulltext
          },
          "recurrence": {
            "pattern": {
                "type": "daily",
                "interval": 1,
            },
            "range": {
                "type": "endDate",
                "startDate": followup,
                "endDate": end_date
            }
          },
        "reminderMinutesBeforeStart": 15,
        "isOnlineMeeting": false,
        "onlineMeetingProvider": "unknown",
        "isReminderOn": true,
        "hideAttendees": false,
        "categories": []
      },
      json: true };
```

i tried like this but it is getting updated all events

Answer (score 0):

Please try first to get the list of occurrences,by using get method

GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/events/{id}/instances?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Then use the Patch API to update the event by providing event_id of occurrences -

PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendar/events/{id}

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the quick reply,will refer the link and check it,thanks